# Understand python code to create population pyramid

Tags: bar-chart, population

I've found this really cool plot ([matplotlib visualizations](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/plots/top-50-matplotlib-visualizations-the-master-plots-python/)) to make a population pyramid. I would like to change the condition for the colors. Instead of men/women, I want to have the whole bars in the same color and this color depends on the tag that I write on Gender. So, some whole bars in blue and the rest in purple.

But I don't understand how the colors are generated.

I imagined that removing the .unique() in df[group_col].unique() would work, but it doesn't plot anything when I switch the tag.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Read data
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/selva86/datasets/master/email_campaign_funnel.csv")

# Draw Plot
plt.figure(figsize=(13,10), dpi= 80)
group_col = 'Gender'
order_of_bars = df.Stage.unique()[::-1]
colors = [plt.cm.Spectral(i/float(len(df[group_col].unique())-1)) for i in range(len(df[group_col].unique()))]

for c, group in zip(colors, df[group_col].unique()):
    sns.barplot(x='Users', y='Stage', data=df.loc[df[group_col]==group, :], order=order_of_bars, color=c, label=group)

# Decorations    
plt.xlabel("$Users$")
plt.ylabel("Stage of Purchase")
plt.yticks(fontsize=12)
plt.title("Population Pyramid of the Marketing Funnel", fontsize=22)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[Pyramid plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcz6M.png)

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Colors are generated on the `colors` variable at `Draw Plot` section

Comment: But what does [plt.cm.Spectral(i/float(len(df[group_col].unique())-1)) for i in range(len(df[group_col].unique()))]
do?

Comment: You should read on matplotlib.pyplot documentation for that

Comment: "*You should read on matplotlib.pyplot documentation for that*". Classy.